# Escape a nested IF statement and evaluate the variable against parent condition

Tags: c#, parsing, nested-if

I have a file parser that evaluates each line of a txt file against a condition. If the condition is met, the subsequent lines in the file are evaluated against a series of nested IF statements. 
What I would like to do is break out of the nested IF statements once the parent condition is met again, then evaluate the line that broke against the parent and have it trigger the nested evaluations again. I am doing this because all of the nested IF statements pull data about the parent item. when i hit another parent item, escape child evaluations and start again.

is this an poor way of handling the situation?

here is  my pseudo code

```
if (line.Contains(":rule ("))
{
    bInRuleFlag = true;

    while (bInRuleFlag == true)
    {
        if (line.Contains(":rule ("))
        {
            bInRuleFlag = false;
            // I have hit a parent element.
            // escape the while loop here and evaluate line against  the parent IF
        }
        else if (line.contatins(""))
        {
            //gets child elements to the rule
        }
        else if (line.contatins(""))
        {
            //gets child elements to the rule
        }
    }
```

}

I would appreciate any advice about better ways to do it if this is incorrect.

Comment: It's a job for a trivial [FSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably just got rid of the outer if statement all together, and your code will work like what you described.

```
while (line.Contains(":rule ("))
{
    if (line.contatins(""))
    {
        //gets child elements to the rule
    }
    else if (line.contatins(""))
    {
        //gets child elements to the rule
    }
}
```

---

also, you can use the `break` command to break out of your **while loop**

```
    if (line.Contains(":rule ("))
    {
        break;
    }
```

---

If you just want to stop there, and go directly to the next iteration of the loop, then you can use the `continue` keyword

```
    if (line.Contains(":rule ("))
    {
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: I dont think this will work because the child elements are on the next lines.   Wouldnt the while loop break right after the first line?

Comment: Do you mean if the `parent` found then `continue` loop with next line ? If thats the case then use the `continue`.

Comment: @user2219930 it's doing exactly what the code you've posted is doing

Comment: @user2219930 you still need a condition to break out of your loop